# Not getting expected results from complex view

Tags: mapreduce, couchdb, couchdb-futon

This is a somewhat involved question as the data I am working with is a little large.

I have the following document structure: https://gist.github.com/gaigepr/5b28a7c67ced0cd71e4e

and the following map function: https://gist.github.com/gaigepr/a721bcc8ef6f681f3807

A little description, this function goes through the example document to collect a list of all combinations of characters from 1 to 5 and supplies them with a 1 or 0 to indicate a win or a loss for that particular combo of characters. This is accomplished by getting the powerset of the team and ignoring the empty set when emitting the array key and integer to indicate a win or loss.

The problem I am having is with reducing the data. My goal is to get the win rate of a particular group of characters in the game this data is from. the view takes a key formatted as such: `[1]` and should output the win rate and games played by that pair of characters.

so my reduce function *should* be something like this:

[image: My reduce function only sees 2 games played somehow]

However when I do this, I do not actually get all the games played by that pair in the reduction. in my test database, I have 96 games played by the above pair `[1, 18]` but when I run map and reduce on the with that key, I get that there were only 2 games played and `null` for the win rate.

A note: This seems to only happen inconsistently. With my data, when I query with the key `[1, 18]` I get accurate results.

[image: As you can see, there are a lot of games associated with key <code>[1]</code>]

I am a little bit at a loss for what to do to debug this and would appreciate some help. I am happy to add more details, gists, even pictures of the futon output if that would be helpful.

I do not have a lot of reason for this yet, or confirmation, but it seems that the data passed to the reduce function is not formatted how I expect it to be but I am not sure why that is.

Comment: Can you tell what should the expected output be for the gists that you have provided? I ran them for the pair [1,20] and got back what looked like correct results to me with `reduce = false`.

Comment: The problem isn't with map, I also get the expected results; something like this: `{[1]: 0, [1]: 1}`. However ahen I reduce I might get a winrate of 1 because for some reason not all games get calculated in the reduce. Also this view is designed to only be useful when passed a key, if that was not clear.

Comment: I reworded a little bit and added pictures of results from map and reduce.

Comment: Can you give the http queries that you use for the key value pair [1,18]?

Comment: If possible could you upload your database to cloudant or iriscouch so that it is more easier to test?

Comment: Here is a link, https://gaigepr.cloudant.com/dashboard.html#/database/test/_all_docs

Comment: I will need your username though so I can add you to the group to use it.